# When I use rewind_post() it shows menu items in my loop

Tags: php, author

I have code like below (I removed all the uneeded HTML and stuff for this post).  The code is for my author.php page.

So it shows some author data at the top of the page then runs `rewind_post()` so it can show the post's by that user.

The problem is for the admin, it is showing all the menu items as post in this loop/list

```
<?php
get_header();

if (have_posts()) :
    the_post();
?>

    View my website:<a href="<?php the_author_meta('user_url'); ?>"></a>

<?php } ?>

<?PHP
    rewind_posts();
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        $format = get_post_format();
        if ( false === $format ){
            $format = 'standard';
        }
        get_template_part( 'format', $format );

    endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the file included in the get_template_part is simply the basic stuff like `<?php the_content(__( 'read more...', 'vigilance' )); ?>`

Comment: I found the answer, it wont let me answer for 8 hours though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, this function was causing the problem....

```
function include_custom_post_types( $query ) {
$custom_post_type = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
    if ( is_archive() ) {
    if ( empty( $custom_post_type ) ) $query->set( 'post_type' , get_post_types() );
}
if ( is_search() ) {
    if ( empty( $custom_post_type ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type' , array(
            'post', 'page', 'website_bookmarks'));
    }
}
return $query;
}
```